# Replace selected data

Tags: replace, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two columns and I need to delete the cells that begin with a set of characters, like this:

```
Product ID  SKU
30  BTO-R-50g
66  BTO-N-250-Box
93  Nile-Single
94  BTO-Nile-Double
95  BTO-Nile-Triple
96  Scarab-Single
97  BTO-Scarab-Double
```

I need to delete all the cells that begin with "BTO". I tried using find and replace function with the "BTO" followed by the wildcard * (BTO*) but the operation gives me a null result basically.

Any tips on how to write a proper string for the replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Data** > **Filter Views...** > **Create New Filter View**.
2. At **A1** Cell click the **little Arrow on the right**.
3. Click **Filter By Condition**.
4. Select **Text Does Not Contain**.
5. Enter the Value : **BTO**
6. Click **OK**.